# Abbreviating a list of existing variables in R

Tags: r, stata

I would like to abreviate a list of existing variables in R as I can do in Stata:
If I have  variables pop1,pop2,pop3a, I can abreviate them as pop* in Stata. Is this possible in R?
I would like to see if it would be possible to rewrite:

`cgmreg  lexpr dd6_*m dd6_*l2 dummy_Y* dummy_ORI* dummy_DES* ,cluster(country_o country_d year)`

from Stata as in R.
I have it as:
`model1 <- plm(lexpr ~ dd6_*m + dd6_*l2 + dummy_Y* + dummy_ORI* + dummy_DES*,  data = bilateral_trade_data, model = "within", effect = "twoways",  index = c("country_o", "country_d", "year"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` it out of data frame `names`, create a formula,

```
(fo <- reformulate(grep('foo|bar', names(df), value=TRUE), 'y'))
# y ~ foo1 + bar2 + foo3 + bar4 + foo5 + bar6 + foo7 + bar8 + foo9 + 
#   bar10
```

and use it in whatever function.

```
plm(fo, ...)
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, 3, 11)) |> setNames(c('y', paste0(c('foo', 'bar'), 1:10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `plm`, but you can use `tidymodels` to do something like this.  `rsample::starts_with()` is a nice helper function.

```r
library(tidymodels)

df <-
  data.frame(
    lexpr = rnorm(10),
    pop1 = rnorm(10),
    pop2 = rnorm(10),
    pop3 = rnorm(10)
  )

rec <-
  recipe(df, lexpr ~ .) %>% 
  update_role(
    starts_with('pop'),
    new_role = 'predictor'
  )

mod <- linear_reg()

wf <- workflow(rec, mod)

fit(wf, df)
#> == Workflow [trained] ==========================================================
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: linear_reg()
#> 
#> -- Preprocessor ----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 0 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> -- Model -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = ..y ~ ., data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         pop1         pop2         pop3  
#>      0.3050      -0.5297      -0.9671       1.0242
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>